# Send response to Http post before executing for loop in php

Tags: php, http, http-post

I have php script which receives post data from Android Application and process it. I need to send response to mobile when post data received itself,then process the data in for loop below.

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "success"; // is it correct way to send response?

$msgData=explode("|",$requestBody);

for($mc=1;$mc<count($msgData);$mc++)
{
   //Run large algorithms with database transactions
}
```

1. How to send to response to mobile before executing for loop?
2. Now this for loop executes properly first time only,then next time run incompletely.

Comment: Have you tried `flush()` after the `echo`?

Comment: also for loop executes first only..then next executes incompletely, is it timeout available for php?

Comment: Check value of `ini_get('max_execution_time')`

Comment: max_execution_time-600.is it seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: That's 10 minutes; btw, if anything fails for any other reason you should set up proper error reporting and logging.

Comment: Thank you.I debug with log file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17544/discussion-between-ram-and-jack)